# The Object you want to instantiate is null when starting server

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime-error

I keep getting this error message for my Rust Server, can someone help?

> Thunder disconnecting: Exception (cs:70821): ArgumentException: The
> Object you want to instantiate is null.
> UnityEngine.Object.CheckNullArgument (System.Object arg, System.String
> message) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
> UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original) (at
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
> EnvironmentFishManager.GenerateFish () (at
> <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)

Comment: `EnvironmentFishManager` is trying to `GenerateFish` but `The Object you want to instantiate is null.` Have you made changes to any fish or the `EnvironmentFishManager` lately?

Comment: @Chuck I don't think this person actually wrote the server. I think they are trying to run the game server for [Rust](https://rust.facepunch.com/).